# What does "gan" mean in "White thy fambles, red thy gan And thy quarrons dainty is."

Tags: meaning-in-context

What the noun ***gan*** mean in the following passage from [the third chapter of James Joyce's Ulysses](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/4300):

*White thy fambles, red thy gan*

*And thy quarrons dainty is.*

*Couch a hogshead with me then.*

*In the darkmans clip and kiss.*

Can the word mean gin - the alcoholic drink? [I looked up ***gan*** in some dictionaries,](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gin) it is written in them that ***gan*** can be a form of the verb gin (meaning begin). I have not found anything of help with regards to ***gan*** as a noun.

Comment: 'Gan' means [mouth](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Farmer-MusaPedestris/the-maunders-praise-of-his-strowling-mort.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OED

> **gan,**
>
> Etymology: Perhaps connected with gane v.; or possibly < Welsh geneu, Cornish ganau, mouth.
>
> *slang.*
>
> **n.1  The mouth.**
>
> 1567   T. Harman Caueat for Commen Cursetors (new ed.) Peddelars Frenche sig. Giiv   Gan, a mouth.
>
> 1652   R. Brome Joviall Crew ii. sig. F4v   This Bowse is better then Rom-bowse, It sets the Gan a gigling.
>
> 1785   in F. Grose Classical Dict. Vulgar Tongue (at cited word)

Answer (score 15):

It's a quotation from "The Maunder’s Praise Of His Strowling Mort" in From The Triumph of Wit, by J. Shirley (1707). It is written in 'Cant', which is a kind of criminal underworld dialect.

> White thy *fambles*, red thy *gan*, [*hand; mouth*]
>   And thy *quarrons* dainty is; [*body*]
>   *Couch a hogshead* with me then, [*sleep*]
>   And in the *darkmans* clip and kiss. [*night*]

[The Maunder’s Praise Of His Strowling Mort](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Farmer-MusaPedestris/the-maunders-praise-of-his-strowling-mort.html)

Comment: This is interesting. The verse appears in Joyce's *Ulysses*. and in the notes [the entire poem is quoted](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Annotations_to_James_Joyce%27s_Ulysses/Proteus/047) and the annotation says it is *The Canting Song* from Richard Head's *The Canting Academy* (1673)

Comment: It is quoted with different sources in different places.

Comment: Yes, it does seem as if Head is merely quoting an existing song - which probably dates from long before him. It is called ***The rogue's delight in praise of his strolling mort***.

Answer (score 4):

Mouth, lips but also the throat. The term is probably of Welsh origin and referred to fish. GDoS has a very early usage example:

***[gan](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/tryepva)***  n.
(also ganns, gans)

> [? Welsh geneu, Cornish ganau, mouth; Scot. gane or ganne, mouth, orig. of a fish; itself linked to Norw. gan, a fish-gill]
>
> (UK Und.) the mouth; in pl., the lips; occas. the throat.
>
> - ***c.1535   [UK]*** R. Copland Hye way to the Spyttel House Eiii: *Cyarum by salmon and thou shalt pek my iere / In thy gan for my watch it is nace gere.*